# How can align css colums vertcally to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, frontend, multiple-columns

Having the following code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wCcfA

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li><a>About</a></li>
  <li><a>Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a>Blog</a></li>
  <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu-main-menu {
  padding: 0;
  height: 77px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 42px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width:250px;
}

#menu-main-menu li{
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

How can I vertically align all the "li" elements at the very bottom of "menu-main-menu" rather than at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I vertically align all the "li" elements at the very bottom of "menu-main-menu" rather than at the top?

I don’t think `vertical-align` can be applied here.

But there is an approach that should work: Using `transform` to first flip the whole menu around on the Y axis – and then again on the list items to flip them “back” to readable:

```
#menu-main-menu {
  /* … */
  -webkit-transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform:scaleY(-1);
}

#menu-main-menu li{
  /* … */
  -webkit-transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform:scaleY(-1);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Abrxl

Of course flipping the menu around changes the order of items – to correct that, their order in the HTML would have to be changed too: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxDsi Whether that’s a compromise your’re willing to make, is for you to decide.

---

I added the `-webkit-` prefixed version and the unprefixed one here, and also the `-moz-` versions of the column properties, yet in Firefox there seem to be some extra margins or something like that going on. That seems to come from applying the columns properties already though, and doesn’t seem to be a result of applying the transformation. Maybe you’ll find a solution to make that look smoother by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `margin-top` every 4n `li` elements like:

```css
#menu-main-menu {
  padding: 0;
  height: 77px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 42px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 250px;
}
#menu-main-menu li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
#menu-main-menu li:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-top: 24px; /*add margin top*/
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
  <li><a>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is a solution, I was looking for something more dynamic/automatic like vertical-align:bottom, as it is a dynamic menu and I would need to write some php counting elements if I do so. I couldn't make vertical-align work. There must be a way to align that to the bottom automatically...